# How to log data on all running processes to use in scheduler simulation?

Tags: linux, logging, process, scheduling

I need to create a process scheduling simulation to test various tweaks of linux's completely fair scheduler, and I need to run it using a log of all the processes running on a system, including how much time they spend using the CPU and in I/O.  My textbook said that the way to do this is to produce a "trace tape" and use this in the simulation, but I can't find any information on how to do this.  How can I log as much information as possible about running processes, including arrival time, resource usage, and time spent waiting for resources?  I'm currently running ubuntu on the machine that this will be used on, but will gladly install whatever flavor of linux would make this easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an interesting project!

Lots of information about each running process can be found in the virtual directory `/proc/[pid]`.  A lot of the information you're after can be found in `/proc/[pid]/stat`.  Perhaps you could write a simple script to read and save the contents of `/proc/*/stat`?

For more info on `/proc`, see http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html